# Change menu to button on small devices

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So i'm new to bootstrap. I have checked the site out an came acros this example on GitHub: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/tree/master/docs/examples/dashboard

This is a little what i need. I can tweak around a little bit to make it work for my needs except for one. There is a sidebar with links. That sidebar disapears when you make you screen smaller (as would have happened on mobile devices). I want to make sure that the sidebar disapears but have it back with a button. Like the top navigation does in this example. Here a snippet from the code (not all is important i assume)

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
    </div>
    <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Dashboard</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Settings</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Help</a></li>
      </ul>
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-right">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search...">
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 sidebar">
      <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Overview <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Reports</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Analytics</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Export</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
        <li><a href="">Nav item</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Nav item again</a></li>
        <li><a href="">One more nav</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Another nav item</a></li>
        <li><a href="">More navigation</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
        <li><a href="">Nav item again</a></li>
        <li><a href="">One more nav</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Another nav item</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

So the `<nav>` hides on smaller devices and forms a menu button

Also a side question, what does that aria mean. I have seen a few aria-... classes but not sure what it does/mean.

Comment: what you exactly want???
on small screen navbar convert into three bar from where you access your menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to display or hide elements based on the screen resolution you can do as follows in your CSS:

```
    @media (max-width: 767px) {
      .nav-sidebar {
        display: none;
      }
    }
    @media (min-width: 767px) {
      .nav-sidebar {
        display: block;
      }
    }
```

the code will display the elements belonging to the class `nav-sidebar` only if the width of the screen is at least `767px`.

You can find a complete example of what you are trying to do here: http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/responsive-navigation-menu